# Select multiple tuples based on hard coded values SQL Query Help

Tags: sql, select, tuples

I want to use a select statement to grab specific tuples based on their ID. So I want to be able to grab col1 from table1 where id = 1,5,9,15 in one query if thats possible. How might I go about doing this?

```
Select col1 from table1 where id = 1 and id = 5...
```

I tried this, but I couldn't get anything. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a single row, the id can't be both 1 and 5 at the same time. That's impossible, so the query will never match any row.

It can be 1 *or* 5, though.

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE id = 1 OR id = 5 ...
```

You can also use the IN syntax:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE id IN (1, 5, 9, 15)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to use OR instead of AND.

```
Select col1 from table1 where id = 1 or id = 5...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `in`:

```
select col1 from table1 where id in (1, 5, 9, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

> grab col1 from table1 where id =
>   1,5,9,15

You want tables IN 1,5,9,15, not =.

```
WHERE id IN (1,5,9,15)
```